# Get the area of specific input world

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I’m looking for a way to get the area of an input world through Wikipedia API or any other module, using python.

For example:

- Python-> programming language
- Bike-> vehicles
- New York -> City

Answer (score 0):

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4068147/7595191), [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4068225/7595191), and closed as too broad before, albeit nearly a decade ago.  I believe the main point from that answer still stands, however:

> Categorization is always highly subjective

Since it had been so long, I did some playing around with various API offerings online and all seem like they have their strong points and weak points.

The Wikipedia API didn't produce great results for me and even searching/scraping pages is going to be tough because - for example - searching for "bike" takes you directly to the bicycle page.  But searching for "New York" takes you to a disambiguation page.  I do not believe you can count on disambiguation to always have the "most desirable" pick at the top of the list.  As an example, a search for `python` returns a disambiguation page with your desired programming language category 9th in the list.  Further, when you get JSON results, they are not segmented such that you can easily pick the "is a" or "refers to a" out unless you search (for example) summary text for some key phrases.

Of the several Word Categorization API's I tested, [WordsAPI](https://www.wordsapi.com/) seems promising.  I was able to get decent results by looking at the `Is an Instance Of` and `Is a Type Of` parts of the response with the examples you provided.  But, it is only available in English (not sure if that's a problem or not).

Wikidata.org also produced some decent results and allows you to sort by "relevance" which helps keep most likely answers at the top.  [Here's a search](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?search=&search=python&title=Special%3ASearch&go=Go&ns0=1&ns120=1) for `python` that actually produces a list with the programming language at the top.

If this were my project, I'd probably start with Wikidata and a BIG list of words with desired categories to test with.  Then work on your parsing logic to catch as many variants as you can as you're ultimately likely to be relying on natural language.

For the record, not one of the API's I tested outside Wikipedia/Wikidata returned anything computer-related for `Python`.